# Dropdown options upward in combobox

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, syncfusion

I'm working on the dropdown field. I'm using Combobox of Syncfusion. My dropdown options are opening downwards. As a result, options are hidden under the screen as it is the last field. I want to open options upward. Is there any way to do it?

**Image of the issue**

[image: Issue]

**Code**

```
<combobox:SfComboBox x:Name="inch" 
    HeightRequest="45" 
    WidthRequest="50"
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    Watermark="inch"
    TextSize="15" 
    DropDownTextSize="14"
    TextColor="#8793EF"
    IsEnabled="{Binding isEnable}"        
    SelectedItem="{Binding Inch}"
    ShowClearButton="False"
    ShowBorder="False">
    <combobox:SfComboBox.ComboBoxSource>
        <ListCollection:List x:TypeArguments="x:String">
            <x:String>0</x:String>
            <x:String>1</x:String>
            <x:String>2</x:String>
            <x:String>3</x:String>
        </ListCollection:List>
    </combobox:SfComboBox.ComboBoxSource>
</combobox:SfComboBox>
```

Comment: Could you please show us your design?

Comment: I have already attached above

Comment: Could you please explain us about the `option`? Please make it detail so that we can give you an answer.

Comment: Options are the values of dropdown. It popups when we click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the SuggestionBoxPlacement property.

SuggestionBoxPlacement="Top"

[Doc Reference](https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/combobox/dealing-with-suggestion-box)